# How do I design a Python API as a backend to a React/JS frontend?

Tags: python, reactjs

I am trying to design a website with a React/JS frontend and a Python backend which does stuff like connecting to AWS Lambda, EC2 etc. Users of this website login via GitHub OAuth.

From my own research and reading so far, it seems that I should use Flask and deploy the backend of the website to some endpoint such as Heroku, where the JS client can then call it.

As for the next steps, I am not totally clear. Should the frontend pass in some kind of token, such as the user's GH token, to persist the data? Otherwise, how does my Python backend know which user's data to fetch and return across sessions?

Answer (score 3):

You're asking a very broad question, that is sure to get many opinionated answers. I'll do my best to point you in a direction to get started without being to opinionated, but make sure to do your own research on top of everything myself and others say.

The number of resources available for web development is massive, and different tech stacks have their own benefits.

## Front End

When working with React, a framework that has been very popular for the past few years is [NextJS](https://nextjs.org/). It acts as an AIO solution for web apps, rendering your frontend, handling routing between pages, and supports [creating an entire API](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/api-routes) within the same project (Python support is available). NextJS was created by [Vercel](https://vercel.com/home), a company that is focused on the hosting side of your web applications - making the entire process simple and user friendly. In addition, solutions for user auth and other popular flows have been built around NextJS, such as [Auth.js](https://authjs.dev/) (previously Next Auth).

Other popular frameworks for React are Remix & Create React App (likely what you use already), but they aren't as "universal" of solutions as NextJS in my view.

On the other end, if you choose to use React independent of Next (or a similar framework), you can choose to host it on an EC2 or similar instance as you've mentioned (though Vercel & [Render](https://render.com/docs/deploy-create-react-app) both still support this). This involves you running installing a web sever like Nginx, running your build command (`npm run build` or `yarn build`), and pointing Nginx to the build build index. Other steps involve setting up scheduling, error management, etc.

## Back End

If you're set on using Python, I know of three main frameworks that are common today for server development.

1. FastAPI - To my knowledge, this is becoming the "go-to" framework for many applications. It's performant, easy to work with, and highly configurable. It has built in request validation and routing and is quite intuitive to work with.
2. Flask - A flexible, lightweight, and popular framework. It doesn't have many of the extra functionalities that Django provides. Flask is more mature than FastAPI, meaning there's likely most support / resources available.
3. Django - A very powerful framework with many built in features such as an ORM, admin panel, user authentication, and API docs generation. It's more complex than the other two frameworks, but is likely a better solution for larger scale apps.

In order to host your service, you can deploy it on an EC2 instance, or similar host. You will again need to setup Nginx (or similar web server) and then you can start your Python server in the way most appropriate for your framework (e.g. gunicorn for FastAPI).

## Communication

When it comes to communicating with your server from the React App, you can use the built in JavaScript [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), pointing your request to the address of your server.

When it comes to user authentication, there are a few approaches; but in short, you likely store a session token (usually in Cookies or local/sessionStorage with JWT), then you send this token to your backend service to validate requests. For GitHub, you specify a callback url, once the user goes through the login flow they are redirected to this url with an authorization code in the redirect. The browser then sends a request to the backend, which then communictes with github to verify the authorization code using the ID and Secret located *on the server*. If this verification completes, the backend sends the session token to your frontend and this is then stored and used for future requests.

---

Unfortunately, there are many things that I don't know and I am restricted to the technologies I have encountered. Hopefully, more knowledgeable SO members can provide further insights, but I hope this at least provides you with some direction. Feel free to ask any follow up questions as well.

Comment: This is a wonderful answer to get me started, thank you!